# WKWebView's title is equal to document.title?

Tags: ios, wkwebview

Just like the question title, I am using `WKWebView` and I want to set the title for the `ViewController`. There are two method:

Method1:

```
self.title = webview.title
```

Method2:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(null_unspecified WKNavigation *)navigation {

    [webView evaluateJavaScript:@"document.title"
              completionHandler:^(id _Nullable ss, NSError * _Nullable error)
    {
        self.title = ss;
    }];
}
```

Are they equal?

Comment: based on the documentation yes, `webview.title` gives you the page title.

Answer (score 2):

No, from what I can tell, at the point of `didFinishNavigation` the web content has loaded, but JS hasn't parsed and run. So if you have a change to `document.title` within the JS parsing event, your previous self.title at this point is stale and incorrect.

Triggering `evaluateJavascript` within `didFinishNavigation` queues the request until after the existing JS has completed and run. And then the `self.title` is correctly applied within the completion block.

If it helps I'm specifically seeing this discrepancy within a React based webView (may have other implications in why the correct title is delayed till after `didFinishNavigation`).